# MySQL row locking with OR

Tags: mysql, locking

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * WHERE accountId = 1 AND (phone = "1234" OR fax = "5678") FOR UPDATE
```

There are keys on all 3 columns in the WHERE clause. accountId is index, phone and fax are combined with accountId to make unique index:

```
UNIQUE KEY `phone` (`phone`,`accountId`),
UNIQUE KEY `phone` (`fax`,`accountId`),
KEY `aid` (`aid`),
```

Which keys will be locked? What I need is to lock rows with phone = "1234" || fax = "5678" for accountId = 1. Is OR optimized correctly or all rows will be locked.

Mysql version is 5.0

Answer (score 0):

try an

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * WHERE accountId = 1 AND (phone = "1234" OR fax = "5678") FOR UPDATE
```

In order to obtain information about how MySQL executes this statement.

Comment: possible keys accountId , phone. key used is accountId. Does this mean that all rows with accountId = 1 will be locked and is there a way to fix this. maybe split it to 2 queries?